# Cut polygon shapefile by line shapefile

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, clip

I have two shapefiles, a polygon shapefile (lake) and a line shapefile (boudary)
I want to create a new shapefile "polygon to the north of the boundary"

[image: I want to create a new polygon "area north of the border line"]

What tool can I use in QGIS or other free GIS for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer provided year before seems to be outdated. An option working with newer versions of QGIS (I'm currently using 3.26):

```
Menu processing > Toolbox > Split with lines
```

Set the polygon as `Input layer` and the line as `Split layer` - and you're done.

Answer (score 26):

There is a QGIS plugin called [Digitizing Tools](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DigitizingTools/):

The [documentation](https://github.com/bstroebl/DigitizingTools/wiki/Usage) says:

**Split selected features with selected line(s) from another layer**

*applies to: line and polygon layer (multi or single part)*

Splits all selected features of the active layer with the selected line features of another layer. The splitting creates new features (not multi features). Each new feature resulting from being split retains its original attributes.

Comment: it worked perfectly!

Comment: @jirikadlec2 fantastic!

Comment: In my experience, it can only split with one selected line at a time (not selected lines). I get the following error message if I try more than one: "Please select only one feature to split with."

Comment: It split my polygon but only kept one half. The other half is gone.

Comment: You may have used 'cut' instead of 'split'

Comment: The "Split Selected Features" tool has been removed in Digitizing Tools Version 1.4.0

The documentation says:
Use processing's in-place editing Split with lines instead.

```To find that in QGIS 3.4, do this:
Go to Processing Toolbox (Ctrl + Alt + T),
scroll down to the Vector Overlay group,
and choose "Split with lines"```