# QGIS splitting features quickly

Tags: qgis, splitting

IS there a way to split blocks in qgis aside from the split features"

for example i want to select a polygon and have it split as required: [image]

is it better to have the lines in a separate layer or have the polygons themselves split ..

EDIT: what im trying to achieve is not splitting the polygon i just want the outline of being split .. that being with a line or by splitting the polygon itself doesnt make a difference

what i need to is speed the process of getting the splitting outline

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Cut polygon shapefile by line shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104526/cut-polygon-shapefile-by-line-shapefile)

Comment: Please define "split as required". What are the requirements? What is your end goal? A map with polygons that look like they have been split into multiple smaller ones?

Comment: i need to be able to select a polygon and split it for example into 8 equal parts.. then select another polygon and have it split into 10 equal parts and so on 

and i don`t need the polygon to be split by even if another line layer appears to split the polygons

if you`d check the second photo i posted it would make it clearer